# Can only delete meeting room calendar item with Full Details (READ permission) in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have given a supervisor custom calendar permissions for meeting rooms. He should be able to delete items in the calendar for those rooms, at least according to the 'Calender properties'. There 'All' is selected under 'Delete items'.

However this doesn't work. Only when he's given 'Full Details' in the Read permissions section, he is able to delete said meetings.

This is not GDPR compliant, he basically can read meeting descriptions and open attached documents.

Is this a bug, or am I overlooking something?

[[image: Calendar permissions[1]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my envoronment and can reproduce this. If you want to delete the items in the calendar, the user must be given "full details" permission. This is by design.